# Windows Ce Compact Framework HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, compact-framework, windows-ce

i am trying to write some data on a `controller` using `rest api`.

But something strange is happening. The first 1, 2, 3 writes are fine but than the application freezes and gets timeouts exceptions am i not closing something?

This is the `code` below:

```
        WebRequest client = (read) ? HttpWebRequest.Create(ReadUri) : HttpWebRequest.Create(WriteUri);
        client.Method = "POST";
        client.ContentType = "application/json";
        CredentialCache creds = new CredentialCache();
        creds.Add(new Uri(WriteUri), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(*******));
        client.Credentials = creds;
        client.PreAuthenticate = true;
        ((HttpWebRequest)client).AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        client.Timeout = 10000;
        //Skipped all data formatting
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(req);
        client.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream dataStream = null; 
        try
        {
            //HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)client.GetResponse();
            dataStream = client.GetRequestStream();

            dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            dataStream.Flush();
            dataStream.Close();
            dataStream.Dispose();
            dataStream = null;

        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            string message = we.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            client = null;
        }
```

Comment: You should probably get the response (after writing to the request stream) and dispose it to release the request from the connection. Otherwise it's keeping the response data until you decide to read from it. Setting `client` to `null` doesn't release anything (not immediately, anyway).

Comment: I tried to listen to the response and worked :) thanks for that! If you make an answer i will vote for you otherwise i will do i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have sent the request, you should process the response and dispose it. If you don't, under the hood the request and its response will remain associated with the connection, and .NET by default only has a few connections available for `WebRequest`s.

```
...
dataStream.Close();
dataStream.Dispose();
dataStream = null;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)client.GetResponse())
{
}
```